# Solve a first order PDE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have some issues when solving the following PDE:

Given that $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\nabla f(x,y)=\left(\frac{n}{2}-x+\frac{n}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{c(x-y)^2+1},\frac{n}{2}-y+\frac{n}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{c(x-y)^2+1}\right),$$
where $c>0$ is some constant and $n$ is some natural number. The boundary conditions are that
$f(n,n)=0$ and $f(x,y)\geq 0$.

I try to first integrate the $\frac{n}{2}-x+\frac{n}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{c(x-y)^2+1}$ with respect to $x$ and then get

$$f(x,y) = \frac{nx}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{c}(x-y)\right) + g(y)
$$

But then, when I differentiate $f$ with respect to $y$ and compare it with $(\frac{n}{2}-y+\frac{n}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{c(x-y)^2+1})$. I found that there is something strange occurs and I cannot solve it for $g(y)$ and thus $f(x,y)$. Is there any alternative way to solve it?

A similar problem occurs when I tried to solve
$$
\nabla f(x,y)=\left(\frac{n}{2}-x+\frac{n}{2}\cdot e^{-c(x-y)^2},\frac{n}{2}-y+\frac{n}{2}\cdot  e^{-c(x-y)^2}\right).
$$

Thank you for your help!

Resolved: as Ivan mentioned, the original equation contradicts to the Schwarz's theorem. Now, it is modified by adding the minus sign in the second term. The method should work now.

The following is the modified problem.

Given that $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\nabla f(x,y)=\left(\frac{n}{2}-x+\frac{n}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{c(x-y)^2+1},\frac{n}{2}-y+\frac{-n}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{c(x-y)^2+1}\right),$$
where $c>0$ is some constant and $n$ is some natural number. The boundary conditions are that
$f(n,n)=0$ and $f(x,y)\geq 0$.

Comment: Gradient components cannot be arbitrary as for most functions $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you for your comment. While I am a bit confused since in this case, the second order derivatives for them are the same.  And how can we proceed to solve it analytically in this case?

Comment: They are not the same. $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}=\frac{c n (x-y)}{\left(c (x-y)^2+1\right)^2}$,  $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}=-\frac{c n (x-y)}{\left(c (x-y)^2+1\right)^2}$. I believe, your equation contradicts to Schwarz's theorem.

Comment: It looks as though there should be a minus sign on one of the $1/[c(x-y)^2+1]$ terms. You might want to check the original problem statement. A similar problem occurs with the $\exp[-c(x-y)^2]$ terms in the second problem.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Yes, you are right. I will modify the question now. I think now it should work.

Comment: @eyeballfrog  Yes, you are right. I will modify the question now. I think now it should work by the original method.

Comment: Did you modify the sign? I don't see it is somehow changed.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Yes, now, it should work!

Comment: Now that the $\nabla f$ components have been fixed up, the solution is straightforward $$f = \frac{n (x + y)}{2} - \frac{x^{2} + y^{2}}{2} + \frac{n}{2 \sqrt{c}} \arctan(\sqrt{c}(x - y)) + A$$ with $A$ a constant. However, I'm not sure you can enforce $f$ to be strictly positive though as $-x^{2} - y^{2}$ is unbounded for $x, y \to \pm \infty$ and grows faster than $x + y$ while $\arctan$ is bounded.